# In-App purchase storing the purchase state

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, xcode4.3

I am implementing in-app purchase to my iPhone App. I am following with this tutorial http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2012/04/implementing-inapp-purchase-in-xcode.html and everything working fine.

But in the above tutorial purchase state is saving in the Phone KeyChain Utility. We can able to purchase it only once.

The second time when i downloaded the App it installs with purchased state .

In in-app purchases purchase should be unique to Apple ID or Device or Both ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you create product as Non-Consumable then it will allow only once to buy.

Comment: No its already Non-Consumable. But how to reset the purchase with an extra button. My client want to recheck it again and again.

Comment: products are purchased only once by a particular user. Once a non-consumable product is purchased, it is provided to all devices associated with that user’s iTunes account

Comment: Yes Romit you are right. But i just want to know my client is really interested in reset and checking the purchase again and again. how can i determine whether the user purchased or not ? Please help me.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html go through this link

Comment: bro im in a hurry. I know this will be in apples document. But if you can done you can help me. How to check whether the product is purchased or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any possibility to undo a purchase of a non-consumable product, neither on the device nor in iTunes Connect. So you have to either test your in-app purchases with a consumable product, or you need to delete your test user in iTunes Connect and register a new one.